# Splitting Lists In Python

Tags: python-2.7

How can I go about splitting a list into 2 separate lists based on every 5 numbers. This is what im trying to get it to look like.

```
    list = [a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,d]

    newlista = [a,a,a,a,a,c,c,c,c,c]
    newlistb = [b,b,b,b,b,d,d,d,d,d]
```

Ive been looking at itertools, not sure if im on the right path.

Comment: So do you want to take five consecutive elements in a list and piece them into new lists and alternate back and forth or are you trying to look for a boundary where the sequence is different and you split on that?  The number of consecutive elements for each character is equal to five as well so it's a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with list comprehension and slices:

```
In [1]: a, b, c, d, = 1, 2, 3, 4
In [2]: l = [a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,d]
In [3]: [l[i:i+5] for i in range(0,15,10)]
Out[3]: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
In [4]: [l[i:i+5] for i in range(5,20,10)]
Out[4]: [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
```